# Does a Defendant LLC that is getting sued under two business names get named and served as Defendant once or twice?

Tags: process, service

Let's say "CompanyName" LLC is being sued for its business activities under the business names "FirstAssumedName" and "SecondAssumedName". Does a Plaintiff name and serve the "CompanyName" LLC once or twice for each business name?

Comment: Why would you not just name "CompanyName LLC dba FirstAssumedName, dba SecondAssumedName"? You should only really serve the "CompanyName LLC", but you can clarify the DBA in the paperwork.

Comment: It is only one entity. Like a person  - Michael, AKA Big Mike. Two names isn't  two people.

Answer (score 3):

### You sue the legal person

One of the things that distinguishes legal personhood from other structures is the ability to sue and be sued. You can't sue a business name or a trust for example but you can sue a company.

I have in fact been required to make adjudication decisions that I know will be unenforceable in court because the applicant named a trust rather than the trustee.